# What is an "Einstein transformation" in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, vector-fields

When introducing the [vielbein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_formalism_(physics)) formalism in [general relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_formalism_(physics)), I came across the use of an *infinitesimal general transformation*, or *Einstein transformation*. The latter term seems to not be covered on standard references, so my asking here.

I quote the lectures in which I found this term: [Horatiu Nastase - Introduction to Supergravity](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.3502), p.12, right above (2.2).

> On both the metric and the vielbein we have also general coordinate transformations.
>   We can check that an infinitesimal general coordinate transformation ("Einstein" transformation) $\delta x^\mu = \xi^\mu$ acting on the metric gives
>   $$ \tag{2.2} (\delta_\xi g)_{\mu\nu} (x)
> = (\xi^\rho \partial_\rho) g_{\mu\nu}
> + (\partial_\mu \xi^\rho) g_{\rho\nu}
> + (\partial_\nu \xi^\rho) g_{\rho \nu}
> $$
>   where the first term corresponds to a translation (the linear term in the Fourier expansion of a field), but there are extra terms.
>   Thus the general coordinate transformations are the general relativity version,
>   i.e. the *local* version of the (global) $P_\mu$ translations in special relativity
>   (in special relativity we have a global parameter $\xi^\mu$, but now we have a local $\xi^\mu(x)$).

1. What is meant by an *Einstein transformation*?
2. What is meant with $\delta_\xi$, and how is the relation **(2.2)** obtained?
3. The following transformation for the vielbein is given:
   $$ \tag{2.3} (\delta_\xi e)_\mu^a(x) = (\xi^\rho \partial_\rho) e_\mu^a
   + ( \partial_\mu \xi^\rho) e_\rho^a. $$
   Why is this relation different from **(2.2)**? Why is the last term missing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure $\delta_\xi$ is just the Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_\xi$ in strange notation.

Comment: @0celo7 and how can I write it in coordinates notation? A simple
$$ g_{\mu\nu}(x) \rightarrow g_{\mu\nu}(x+\xi(x))$$
only gives the first term in **(2.2)**

Comment: the metric at the point $x+\xi(x)$ is, in general, different from the metric at $x$, so perhaps you have to transform that as well through $\xi^\mu_{,\nu}$

Comment: I guess its just the Lie derivative wrt a vector field $$\xi$$..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comments to the question (v3):

1. $\delta_\xi\equiv {\cal L}_\xi$ is a [Lie-derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative) wrt. the vector field $\xi$ in the [active picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation), or a general coordinate transformation in the passive picture.
2. The terminology [Einstein transformation](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=einstein+transformation&as_eq=lorentz) yields (at the time of writing this answer) less than a 1000 Google hits, so we conclude that it is not widely used. It seems to be just another word for the before-mentioned Lie-derivative/coordinate transformation.
3. Concerning the vielbein in eq. (2.3), the before-mentioned Lie-derivative/coordinate transformation does not "act" on a flat index "$a$", so to speak. See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/102722/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142836/2451) Phys.SE posts.