# Difference of connections in the Killing vector equation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, vector-fields

For the [Killing vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field) equation, I sometimes see it written in terms of spin connection $\omega$ and other times in terms of the affine connection $\Gamma$.

More clearly
$$\nabla_{\mu}V_{\nu}+\nabla_{\nu}V_{\mu}=0=\partial_{\mu}V_{\nu}+\Gamma_{\mu\nu\lambda}V^{\lambda}+\partial_{\nu}V_{\mu}+\Gamma_{\nu\mu\lambda}V^{\lambda}$$

Another time, you find it satisfying this
$$\partial_A V_B+\partial_B V_A=\omega_{A,CB}V^C+\omega_{B,CA}V^C$$

What is the difference between the two descriptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments to the question (v3):

1. The [vielbein](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/vielbein) $e^A{}_{\mu}$ in the [Cartan formalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_formalism_%28physics%29) is an intertwiner 
   $$\tag{1} g_{\mu\nu}~=~e^A{}_{\mu} ~\eta_{AB} ~e^B{}_{\nu} $$
   between the curved (pseudo) Riemannian  metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ and the corresponding flat metric $\eta_{AB}$. Here Greek indices $\mu,\nu,\lambda, \ldots,$ are so-called *curved* indices, while capital Roman indices $A,B,C, \ldots,$ are so-called *flat* indices. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142836/2451) related Phys.SE post.
2. The vielbein $e^A{}_{\mu}$ translates the vector field 
   $$V~=~V^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}$$ with curved components $V^{\mu}$ into flat components 
   $$V^A~:=~e^A{}_{\mu} V^{\mu}.$$
3. The [christoffel symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols) $\Gamma^{\lambda,\mu\nu}$ and the [spin connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_connection) $\omega^{AB}_{\mu}$ can be written in terms of the vielbein $e^A{}_{\mu}$, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_connection) for details.
4. TL;DR: Using the vielbein $e^A{}_{\mu}$ as an intertwiner, it is possible to show that OP's various conditions for a [Killing vector field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field) are equivalent.